# How to install Tesserocr on Mac

Tags: install, python, ocr

I'm trying to install [Tesserocr for python](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr)

I'm not sure what the replacement for `apt-get` in `apt-get install tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev` is in this case. I'm new to this and don't fully understand how it works.

I installed `tesseract` successfully, but I think (to my understanding) `tesseract` is a command line program. I check `brew` but I don't think `brew` has it.

Comment: [Do I need to install pip?](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) & `pip install tesserocr` and maybe one of virtualenv or pyenv

Comment: I mean thats fine, but I think the issue here is that I don't see a way to install the requirement packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install tesserocr's dependencies on macOS, you can use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/). These install the C/C++ libraries and executables that are needed.

For either of them you need to install the base package manager the install tesseract

For Homebrew `brew install tesseract`

For Macports `sudo port install teseract`

After that you will be able to install you **tesserocr** wrapper using `pip install` without errors:

```
pip install tesserocr
```

Comment: it work! Just so I can understand how it works next time, `brew install tesseract` installs the requirement packages and `pip install tesserocr` installs the ocr right?

Comment: `brew` installs the tesseract binaries; these are written in C++ and have to be compiled and installed on your computer. `pip` installs the python library that interfaces with the tesseract binaries.